# Horizontally Placed Equal Width Equal Horizontal Space Buttons With Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have written the following code to achieve

> Horizontally spaced equal width fixed height equal horizontal spaced three button but somehow it's not working fine. Can anyone rectify this ?

```
UIButton *cancelBtn = [UIButton new];

cancelBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, (popupView.bounds.size.width-40)/3, 30);

[cancelBtn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cancelBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cancelBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

[popupView addSubview:cancelBtn];



UIButton *resetBtn = [UIButton new];

resetBtn.frame = CGRectMake(cancelBtn.frame.origin.x+cancelBtn.bounds.size.width+10, 5, (popupView.bounds.size.width-40)/3, 30);

[resetBtn setTitle:@"Reset" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[resetBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[resetBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

[popupView addSubview:resetBtn];




UIButton *doneBtn = [UIButton new];

doneBtn.frame = CGRectMake(popupView.bounds.size.width-10-((popupView.bounds.size.width-40)/3), 5, (popupView.bounds.size.width-40)/3, 30);

[doneBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[popupView addSubview:doneBtn];





cancelBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[cancelBtn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:30]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f] ];


[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f]];
 resetBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[resetBtn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:30]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f] ];


[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f]];


[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f]];



doneBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


[doneBtn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:30]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f] ];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f]];
[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint     constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

How to fix this ?

I want to achieve a popup like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9IjC.png)

Comment: what is popup view? is it a UIView?

Comment: @_elk_cloner   yes it's a uiview which has a UIDatePicker in it which is appearing fine .

Comment: @KoustavBasu can you please share any screenshot showing how you are currently getting the output

Comment: How to post image here ?

Comment: kindly check I have posted an answer with two image link to explain how things are appearing.  @AravindAR

Comment: @KoustavBasu ok

Comment: Is the issue resolved ? @AravindAR

Comment: @KoustavBasu nope trying out.

Comment: Hello @AravindAR good morning.

Any update to my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

use **stackView** instead of UIView there are lots of flexibility.

You don't have to think about child view's autolayout inside stackView.

Stack View has a bunch of features to satisfy your needs

**Code:**

```
-(void)createStackViewWithButton {

UIButton *doneBtn = [UIButton new];
[doneBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[doneBtn.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[doneBtn.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;


UIButton *doneBtn2 = [UIButton new];
[doneBtn2 setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

[doneBtn2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[doneBtn2.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;



UIButton *doneBtn3 = [UIButton new];
[doneBtn3 setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn3 setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[doneBtn3.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[doneBtn3.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;




UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];

stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing;
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
stackView.spacing = 0;

[stackView addArrangedSubview:doneBtn];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:doneBtn2];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:doneBtn3];

stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.view addSubview:stackView];


//Layout for Stack View
[stackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = true;
[stackView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = true;

}
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: I have already implemented lot of things in that view. Isn't it possible to do the thing in a way like i tried in the above code. ?

Comment: how did you added image ? My image is appearing as a hyperlink only.

Answer (score 0):

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAOS8.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meIok.png)

They are appearing one over another.

Comment: did u copy paste my code? my code is working fine. just take another sample viewcontroller and drop the function I wrote

Comment: @elk_cloner The thing I want won't be possible with stack view I guess. The three button with Y position 5 px from the top of pope-view and x of left most button and the gap between all three buttons are 10 and trailing space between right most button and the pope-view edge is 10. When the middle button disappears on some condition the left and right button width increases and maintain the leading trailing and in between space of 10px.And if I rotate the screen the things will be same.
P.S: Button width will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED ! Fixed it.**

```
UIButton *cancelBtn = [UIButton new];

cancelBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, (popupView.bounds.size.width-40)/3, 30);

[cancelBtn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cancelBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cancelBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

[popupView addSubview:cancelBtn];



UIButton *resetBtn = [UIButton new];

resetBtn.frame = CGRectMake(cancelBtn.frame.origin.x+cancelBtn.bounds.size.width+10, 5, (popupView.bounds.size.width-40)/3, 30);

[resetBtn setTitle:@"Reset" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[resetBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[resetBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

[popupView addSubview:resetBtn];




UIButton *doneBtn = [UIButton new];

doneBtn.frame = CGRectMake(resetBtn.frame.origin.x+resetBtn.bounds.size.width+10, 5, (popupView.bounds.size.width-40)/3, 30);

[doneBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[doneBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[popupView addSubview:doneBtn];





cancelBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[cancelBtn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:30]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f] ];


[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f]];




resetBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[resetBtn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:30]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f] ];




[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f]];


[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f]];



 doneBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


[doneBtn addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:30]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f] ];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:popupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f]];
```

// +++++++ Equal width constraints +++++++

```
[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];

[popupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:resetBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:doneBtn attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];
```